# Jscript runtime error object required

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error in .js file as

```
d.style.visibility='hidden';
```

What is d here I dont know,I have used a ckeditor replaced with the textbox as txtEditorAnswer.

Can anybody help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope your html is like this

```
<html>
<div>
 <input type="text" id="txtEditorAnswer" />
</div>
</html>
```

And what i think you need is to hide the txtEditorAnswer
For this you need not create any variable .Just copy down the code below

It is for hiding the particular element.It is happen because u r not initializing the "d".
If u want to set the visibilty hidden u just use like this

```
document.getElementById('txtEditorAnswer').style.display = 'none'
```

If u r using asp:textbox u might change to its client ID

```
 document.getElementById('<%=txtEditorAnswer.ClientID%').style.display = 'none'
```

I hope the problem is due to the d is null always.I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: var txtEditorAnswer = document.getElementById('txtEditorAnswer').style.display = 'none';but its not working...anything more idea u suggest

Comment: if(!d)throw '[CKEDITOR.editor.replace] The element with id or name "'+b+'" was not found.';

Comment: @Srivastava i said because txtEditorAnswer will be some thing like a textbox

Comment: why u r using var txtEditorAnswer ? document.getElementById('txtEditorAnswer').style.display = 'none'; is enough